# Change a 2-by-4 matrix into a 2-by-2-by-4 one

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have the matrix

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16];
```

I would generate the matrix `B` with size `[2,2,4]` such that

```
B(:,:,1) = [1 2; 5 6];
B(:,:,2) = [9 10; 13 14];
B(:,:,3) = [3 4; 7 8];
B(:,:,4) = [11 12; 15 16];
```

How can I generate this 3D matrix?

Comment: What are you going to do with these subarrays once you have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using `mat2cell`:

```
dim1 = [2,2];                 %first dimension of the submatrix
dim2 = [2,2];                 %second dimension of the submatrix
C = mat2cell(A,dim1,dim2)     %for square submatrix C=mat2cell(A,dim1) work also
B = reshape([C{:}],[2,2,4])
```

Comment: Is this really the fastest? They have equal sizes all around, so going through a cell sounds slow (at least, in my experience staying within N-D matrices is faster if possible). You might need to do fancy ND `permute()` and `reshape()` though

Comment: I've never said that it is fast or the fastest ! It is just easy to use.

Comment: It is basically equal to the solution I had thought. However, I was curious if there extsts a method without using mat2cell which can slow the process in case of very large matices.

Comment: You can also use `reshape(permute(reshape(A.',[4,2,2]),[2,1,3]),[2,2,4])` for example, but it's a bit ugly.